# Non-Surjective Function

Tags: matrices, functions

I'm reading an introductory text on abstract algebra, without the benefit of any recent experience with matrices or linear algebra.

The text includes a statement that a map from $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{M(R)}$ given by

$$
    g(r) =    \left(\begin{matrix}
               0 & 0\\
               -r & r \\
               \end{matrix}\right)
$$

is injective but not surjective.

Can someone explain, in non-technical terms, why the map isn't surjective?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What $r$ would you choose to get the identity matrix? Or any matrix that has a non-zero entry in the top row?

Comment: For it to be surjective, every point in $\mathbb{M}(\mathbb{R})$ would have to be the image of a point. But anything with non-zero coefficients in the first row clearly can't be in the image of $g$!

Comment: Unfortunately, it's been many years since I've even thought about matrices....  I'm really trying just to get a layman's understanding of why, given the matrix, I can't find my way back to the r in g(r).  Sorry for my lack of knowledge in this area!

Comment: You may be mistaken about what "surjective" means (it means "onto" the range, so the image equals the range). But you are right, given the $g(r)$, you certainly can find your way back to the unique $r$ (it's just the lower right entry). So you have shown that $g$ is **injective** (1-1), not that it is surjective.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for your patient explanations.  As I said, it's been a long, long time since I've given any thought to these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such a function to be surjective, then given a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$, there would have to exist an $r$ such that $g(r) = A$ (that is, every element in the codomain has an $r$ in the domain corresponding to it). But consider the matrix $$A = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{array}\right)$$

Recall that two matrices are equal $\iff$ they have the same entries at every position. Then if we had an $r$ such that $g(r) = A$, then

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ r & -r\end{array}\right) \implies 1 = 0$$

by considering the top left entry. No choice of $r$ lets this happen, so no such $r$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

Remember: a function $f:A\to B$ is called *surjective* if for every element $b\in B$, we can find (at least one) $a\in A$ with $f(a)=b$.

That is: every point in $B$ is attainable as a function value.

In the question at hand, this would require that absolutely any $2\times 2$ matrix with real entries could be written as $g(r)$ for some $r$. But, for instance, the identity matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\neq g(r)\text{ for any }r\in\mathbb{R},
$$
because $g(r)$ always has a $0$ in the top-left corner.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Do you think every ($2\times 2$) matrix can be written in the form you have given? That would have to be the case if $g$ were surjective; the image of $g$ would have to "cover" every such matrix.

Comment: I think I've got it now.  I was focusing on the domain of g and not the range of g.  Thank you for clarifying.